# Techniques for (upper-)bounding LP maximization

Tags: linear-programming

I have a huge maximization linear program (variables grow as a factorial of a parameter). I would like to bound the objective function *from above*. I know that looking at the dual bounds the objective function of the primal program from below.

I know the structure of the constraints (I know how they are generated, from all permutations of a certain set). I am asking if there are some techniques to find an upper bound on the value of the objective function. I realize that the technique is very dependent on the structure of the constraints, but I am hoping to find many techniques so that hopefully one of them would be suitable for my linear program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In determining the value of a primal maximization problem, primal solutions give lower bounds and dual solutions give upper bounds. There's really only one technique for getting good solutions to large, structured LPs, and that's [column generation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delayed_column-generation), which involves solving a problem-specific optimization problem over the set of variables.